# Generics inheritance in views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

My XAML looks like:

```
<local:BasePage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:FinishOrderViewModel"
...
```

Code behind looks like

```
public sealed partial class FinishOrderView : BasePage<FinishOrderViewModel>
...
```

Then I get next error in XAML:
*The name "BasePage`1" does not exist in the namespace "using:DT.MainLib.WP.Views"*

What I do wrong? Any answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post a bit more code, show us what worked and what doesnt.